# Is it possible to start recording video for an existing page in Playwright?

Tags: playwright

I'm connecting to a running Chrome instance with playwright's `connectOverCDP` method. Is it possible to start recording video for the context that's already opened instead of creating a new one with `recordVideo` turned on?

Comment: This is not supported, video recording can only be enabled when creating a context and stopped when closing the context. I'd recommend to file a feature request if you are interested in your proposed feature.